# Using a front end editor with static pages plugin

Tags: php, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

Im really new to ocms, I have installed static pages and its working really good. I want to edit the fields from the front page (in context editing) with one of the plugins, this for example: https://octobercms.com/plugin/netsti-editor I have dragged to my layout page, but I can't edit this in the front page. this is an example how I use the static page plugin:

```
<img src="{mediafinder name="logo" label="Logo" tab="General" mode="image"}{/mediafinder}" />

{repeater name="side_logos" tab="General" prompt="Add another content section"} {text name="my_title" label="My Title"}{/text} {/repeater}
```

Thanks

Comment: can you post raw html output of that template expression?

Comment: @camel_case , can you please explain? you want the page output while im logged in? or something else?

Comment: this code transpiles to html eventually during rendering, can you post how html code actually looks like after the page is rendered by a browser? right click -> View Page Source

Comment: @camel_case https://paste.ofcode.org/6vb9H6R5y6uFXdbQfTKyHz

Comment: I assume this is an output when you're not logged in right?

Comment: @camel_case - logged in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155051/discussion-between-shazam-and-camel-case).

Comment: I don't see any js library loaded that allow you to edit the page, are you sure you're not missing any?

Comment: @camel_case , lets continue here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155051/discussion-between-shazam-and-camel-case

Answer (score 3):

We discussed the exact problem with the OP in a chat. Turned out that there's a better option to use other plugins for his needs - [this one for static pages](http://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-pages) and [this one for inline editing](https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-editable).

The other thing is, once page becomes more or less dynamic (e.g. scripts that can change/alter any type of content) it automatically stops being "static page".